# How to change WooCommerce checkout widget order summary column width

Tags: css, woocommerce, checkout, datastax-astra

I'm using Astra theme and WooCommerce checkout widget. The first column in order summary is too narrow so it compresses the name of the product. How to change first column width?

[image]

Comment: You should easily be able to do this with css! Can you link the site and products you added?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found the css which is controlling it. Changed max-width to 300px and it looks better now.

`.elementor-widget-woocommerce-checkout-page .woocommerce .woocommerce-checkout-review-order-table .cart_item td.product-name { padding-right: 40px; max-width: 150px; }`